# Usando Factory e Controller para tratar Json

Tags: c#, controller

Neste site [Andrew McGivery](http://mcgivery.com/ionic-using-factories-and-web-services-for-dynamic-data/) encontrei este exemplo bem interessante:

```
.controller('UserCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, userService) {
        var user = userService.getUser($scope.id);
    })
```

---

```
.factory('userService', function($http) {
    var users = [];

    return {
        getUsers: function(){
            return $http.get("https://www.yoursite.com/users").then(function(response){
                users = response;
                return users;
            });
        },
        getUser: function(id){
            for(i=0;i<users.length;i++){
                if(users[i].id == id){
                    return users[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
})
```

Eu gostaria de saber como faria para retornar todos os usuários se tivesse mais de um usuário com o mesmo id?

Comment: C# ou AngularJs?

Comment: C#, mas se conseguir passar um pouco de cada fico grato.

Comment: Mas qual é o problema?

Comment: Eu quero listar todos os itens de determinada conta, e estou usando um modelo parecido ao exemplo acima. Onde ele verifica se o idcliente é igual ao idcliente dentro da tabela de itens e assim poder mostrar.

Comment: Não entendi bem tua duvida, vc pode retornar uma lista sem problemas da mesma forma que retorna um registro. nesse caso vc irá tratar algo semelhante a consulta com um usuário, entretanto tua aplicação deve retornar uma lista

Comment: A aplicação é ASP.NET MVC ou Web API 2?

Comment: Web API 2. Usando "return users[i];" vai retornar um único registro, correto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Só inserir a uma lista e no final do `for` retornar o resultado, desta forma:

```
getUser: function(id){
    var users = [];
    for(i=0;i<users.length;i++){
        if(users[i].id == id){
            users.push(users[i]);
        }
    }
    return users;
}
```